# gdb on host shows stack is corrupt

Tags: linux, gdb

I have a application core file that was generated on an x86 target machine. All the libraries and binaries are stripped and so the back trace when running on the target is very minimal to nothing. i still do see the symbol name and back trace.

However, if i move the core file to a host machine and run the gdb for x86 on the host, provide it with sysroot , it complains with the following.

cannot load memory at address 0x104

Any ideas/suggestions why the host complains while the target is ok decoding the back trace?
BTW, all my code has been compiled with -fPIC.

Comment: why do you think the stack is corrupt?

Comment: On host i see this on gdb. any command like set sysroot i see Reading symbols from one.
[New Thread 3822]
[New Thread 3817]
[New Thread 3791]
[New Thread 3795]
[New Thread 3790]
[New Thread 3825]
[New Thread 3826]
[New Thread 3827]
[New Thread 3828]
[New Thread 3824]
[New Thread 3829]
[New Thread 3830]
[New Thread 3831]
[New Thread 3823]
[New Thread 3786]
**Cannot access memory at address 0x1a**

Comment: Can you check for below command and see if the result is same in both? md5sum and file core.*. Basically it is to ensure that you have moved the core file in right format and completely.

Comment: My guess is that the "provide it with sysroot" part is not working. How exactly did you do that?

Comment: i verified that the core file is exactly the same signature and size as the core created on the target. . i do the following:   gdb-7.2 path_to_biniary <core_file>, then set sysroot <complete_path/to/buildroot> . at this point i usually see a list of loading library messages. But for this case, i see "Cannot access memory at address 0x1a"

Answer (score 0):

> i do the following: gdb-7.2 path_to_biniary , then set sysroot

Try this instead:

```
gdb /path/to/binary
(gdb) set sysroot /path/to/buildroot
(gdb) core /path/to/core_file
```

Setting sysroot after the core has already been loaded (as I believe happens in your invocation) is too late.

Comment: just to terminate this thread, i was able to resolve this by going back to an older version of gdb(6.6.1). that did not have this issue.