# How is gdb stack trace readability of release code influenced on x64?

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

I am working on a project, where the request "we want more information in release build stack traces" came up.

With "stack trace" I mean basically the output `of t a a bt` in `gdb`, which I suppose to be equivalent to the output of gstack for a running process. If this is true would be one of my questions.

My main problem is that availability of stack traces is rather erratic (sometimes you have them, sometimes you don't) and documentation could be more detailed (e.g. `gdb` documentation states that "`-fomit-frame-pointer` makes debugging impossible on some machines.", without any clear information about x86_64)

Also, when examining a running program with `gstack`, I get a quite perfect stack traces. I am unsure, though, if this is exactly what I would get from a core dump with `gdb` (which would mean that all cases where I get less information, the stack has been really corrupted).

Currently, the code is compiled with `-O2`. I have seen one stack trace lately, where our own program code's stack frames did not have any function parameter values, but the first (inner) frames, where our code already called a third party library, provided these values. Here, I am not sure if this is a sign that the first party library had better gcc debugging options set, or if these information is just lost at some point iterating down the stack trace.

I guess my questions are:

- Which compiler options influence the stack trace quality on x86_64
- are stack traces from these origins identical:

  - output of `gstack` of a running program
  - attached gdb to a running program, executed `t a a bt`
  - called `gcore` on a running program, opening core with `gdb`, then `t a a bt`
  - program aborted and core file written by system, opened with `gdb`
- Is there some in-depth documentation which parameters affect stack trace quality on x86_64?

All considerations made under the assumption that the program binary exists for the core dump, and source code is not available.

With "quality of a stack trace" i mean 3 criteria:

- called function names are available, not just "??"
- The source codes file name and line number is available
- function call parameters are available.

Comment: What is producing the stack trace? How is the stack trace produced? Is it your code or the system? How do you measure the stack trace quality? In gstack the stack traces are produced by gstack, you can just run your code under gstack every time, why don't you do that? Core dump in gdb is just the memory image of a program with registers status. Debugging information are DWARF or other format information embeeded inside the executable. If a "process dumps core" it usually means call to `abort()`, then it's up to the system what and how it prints.

Comment: Also I wouldn't advise generating release executables with debugging information as that may give a lot of information for reverse engineering thus make it easy to steal your work.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk: I tried to answer your annotations in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which compiler options influence the stack trace quality on x86_64

The `-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default on `x86_64`, and *does not* cause stack traces to be unusable.

GDB relies on unwind descriptors, and you *could* strip these with either `strip` or `-fno-unwind-tables` (this is *ill*-advised).

> are stack traces from these origins identical:
>   - output of gstack of a running program

Last I looked, `gstack` was a trivial shell script that invoked `gdb`, so yes.

> - attached gdb to a running program, executed "t a a bt"

Yes.

> - called gcore on a running program, opening core with gdb, then "t a a bt"

Yes, *provided* the `core` is opened with GDB on the *same* system where `gcore` was run.

> - program aborted and core file written by system, opened with gdb

Same as above.

If you are trying to open `core` on a different system from the one where it was produced, and the binary uses dynamic libraries, you need to `set sysroot` appropriately. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14844969/50617) question and answer.

Note that there are a few reasons stack may look corrupt or unavailable in GDB:

- `-fno-unwind-tables` or `strip`ing mentioned above
- code compiled from assembly, and lacking proper `.cfi` directives
- third party libraries that were built with very old compiler, and have incorrect unwind descriptors (anything before gcc-4.4 was pretty bad).
- and finally, stack corruption.